# Is their any way to disable ion-datetime picker scroll vibration on the device In Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Is their any way to disable ion-datetime picker scroll vibration on the device In Ionic.

I using capacitor 3. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing **@capacitor/haptics** from package.json and package-lock.json